# Run and debug python script inside docker container with VS Code

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have below command to run my python file inside docker container:

```
docker run --rm --name=my_container --volume "/my_dir/:/host:z" myimage:latest python /host/api/my_file.py
```

I want to run it with VS code debug mode.

I tried looking at tutorials from VS code and Docker but most of the instructions are for Django/Flask and I don't understand how to modify it.

Comment: There is documentation on [configuring a launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common) and [remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_remote-debugging) (in case you insist on running the container manually).

Comment: It might be easier to reproduce the error outside Docker, and then use ordinary non-Docker development tooling here (for example, a Python virtual environment).  This approach will also help you write a unit test once you do address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can use command to create a Docker launch configuration to build and run your container in debug mode.Docker: Add Docker Files to Workspace...

1. Navigate to the file that contains your app's startup code, and set
   a breakpoint.
2. Navigate to Run and Debug and select `Docker: Python - General`,
   `Docker: Python - Django`, or `Docker: Python - Flask`, as appropriate.
3. Start debugging using the **F5** key.

You can also refer to [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python) for more details about docker and debug in docker